# How to customize a SELECT and make it works?

Tags: html, css

I customize a select with some choices.
I use a system with opacity and display block/none. But when I have display block and none (my code is there in comments), I can not choose an option in my list.

When I delete or comment the display block and none (two lines in my code, commented here), it works but I can choose and option when I click outside the select...

How can I achieve this and have this select with a good working ?

Thanks for help

```css
.select-box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: gray;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.select-box-content {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}


.label-right-choice {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 88;
}

.choice-values {
    display: flex;
}

.choice {
    font-size: 24px;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

input:checked + .content-choice {
    display: flex;
}
    

.content-choice {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: gray;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}



.select-box-content:focus + ul {
    display: block; /*if I delete this it works but I can choose an element by clicking under the select (behind "other content" for example)*/
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 999;
}
              
       

ul {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: none; /*if I delete this it works but I can choose an element by clicking under the select (behind "other content" for example)*/
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
         
label.listchoice {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid brown;
    color:gray;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mb-4 triple-choice">
    <div class="select-box">
        <div class="select-box-content" tabindex="1">
            <div class="label-right-choice">Choisir</div>
            <div class="choice-values">
                <input type="radio" id="0" value="1" name="rightChoice" checked="checked" />
                <div class="content-choice">
                    <div>Choix 1</div>
                    <div class="choice">aaa</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-values">
                <input type="radio" id="1" value="2" name="rightChoice" />
                <div class="content-choice">
                    <div>Choix 2</div>
                    <div class="choice">bbb</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="choice-values">
                <input type="radio" id="2" value="3" name="rightChoice" />
                <div class="content-choice">
                    <div>Choix 3</div>
                    <div class="choice">ccc</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="listchoice" for="0" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">
                    <div>Choix 1</div>
                    <span class="choice">aaa</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="listchoice" for="1" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">
                    <div class="percent-choice" >Choix 2 </div>
                    <span class="choice">bbb</span>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="listchoice" for="2" aria-hidden="aria-hidden">
                    <div class="percent-choice" >Choix 3</div>
                    <span class="choice">ccc</span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
  <a href="">Other content</a>
</div>
```

In codepen  : https://codepen.io/andrea121/pen/yLPyOWe

Comment: That's not valid CSS. In the CodePen it's labeled as SCSS.

Comment: Thanks I edit my post and transform in CSS to have a snippet more clear.